# Uploading File Error using Fastify and Nestjs

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, file-upload, nestjs

I am trying to upload a file to my nest.js server but I am getting an error:

> Error: Unsupported Media Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------140603536005099484714904

[image: Error File]

I followed this [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload).

**Angular 6 Code**

```
public async Upload<TReponse>(file: File, path) {
    try {

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);

      //>> function to upload and applying header as null

      const result = await this.http.post(this.baseUrl + path, formData, { headers: null }).pipe(map((response: any) => response)).toPromise();
      var response = result as ApiResponseObject<TReponse>;

      return response;
    }
    catch (ex) {
      var result = new ApiResponseObject<TReponse>()
      result.message = ex.message;
      result.isSuccess = false;

      return result;
    }
    finally {
    }
 }
```

**NestJs Code Module Code**

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer, MulterModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from './dto/user.entity';
import * as multer from 'multer';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    MulterModule.register({
        dest: '/public',
        fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            let extension = (file.originalname.split('.').pop())
            //Put here your custom validation for file extensións.
            // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
            cb(null, true);
            // To reject this file pass `false` or throw Exception, like so:
            //cb(new HttpException ("File format is not valid", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST), false)
        },
        limits: {
            fileSize: 2097152 //2 Megabytes
        },
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
            destination(req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, './public');
            },
            filename(req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, "usman_" + file.originalname);
            },
        })
    }),
    ],
    providers: [UserService],
    controllers: [UserController],
})
```

**NestJs Code Component Code**

```
@Post("upload")
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
async upload(@UploadedFile() file, @Request() req) {
    console.log(file);
    console.log(req.files);
}
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, still open questions? :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the `FastifyAdapter` instead of express.
In the documentation it says:

> Multer will not process any form which is not multipart
>   (multipart/form-data). **Besides, this package won't work with the
>   FastifyAdapter.**

So if possible, switch to express. Otherwise, you have to use [Fastify-Multipart](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-multipart) until it is natively supported by nest.js.

Comment: Thank @Kim is there any way to upload file while I have developed half of work. but I am stuck with uploading file. How can we use fastify-multipart with nestjs to upload file? Thanks

Comment: Just follow the documentation of Fastify-Multipart. You won't be able to use the FileInterceptor or the UploadedFile decorator. Either write your own Interceptor/decorator/... or work with the req object. If you have problems along the way, you can open a new question and post the code you have so far. :)